# Open Source/existing C# class to write GPX files? (C#)

Tags: c#, gis, gpx

I am looking for a C# library or class to help write [GPX files](http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp) from a collection of waypoints I have (lat/long, etc).

I have found [quite a few readers](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=511) - but not so much for writing.

Bonus points if it works on Compact Framework/WinMobile 6.5 - but that is not a hard requirement.  I can make it work on a desktop doing post-processing - the Mobile device does not have to build these files.

Does anyone know of some, or a simple way to write the files?

Comment: The quickest way is to simply generete the classes for it using xsd.exe from the xsd at http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd and then serialize it. I personally don't like those generated classes much and wrote a bunch of (simple) wrapper classes to implement the features I needed (so it's not complete). If you need more input about either path just ask :)

Comment: Thanks.  I will look at that - but I really don't need the heavyweight classes - this is just for a set of waypoints and I might just wrap it with something simple...

Comment: Here is a simple java code that is easy to port http://code.google.com/p/osmtracker-android/source/browse/trunk/src/me/guillaumin/android/osmtracker/gpx/GPXFileWriter.java?r=45

Answer (score 7):

Have you taken a look at [OGL (Open GPS-LBS)](http://ogl-lib.sourceforge.net/)?

From the [class docs](http://ogl-lib.sourceforge.net/doc/annotated.html):

> This GPX class provide converts GPS data(waypoints, routes, and
>   tracks) to be compatible with GPX format file.

Regarding the Windows Mobile note, the library supports:

> "...applications on PC(Windows) or PocketPC(CE)."

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (as in most lo-fi, not most time-efficient) way is opening any gpx file in a text editor and pasting your coordinates in the correct spot, or writing a new one as below. GPX is a type of XML-file, so if you know some HTML, it's easy to pick up on.

The most basic format that I can open (using GPX Viewer on Android) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx>
  <!--Waypoint 1-->
  <wpt lat="50.888090" lon="4.698118">
  </wpt>
  <!--Waypoint 2-->
  <wpt lat="50.788090" lon="4.798118">
  </wpt>
  <!--etc-->
  <wpt lat="50.988090" lon="4.618118">
  </wpt>
</gpx>
```

Add or remove waypoints to taste.

Similar things can be done for tracks and routes, and you can add a lot more information like elevation and time, but you'll have to google for GPX documentation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://nettopologysuite.github.io/

It has a GPXFile class https://nettopologysuite.github.io/NetTopologySuite.IO.GPX/

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple way to generate using pure c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {        

        List<int> heartRateList = new List<int>() { 80, 81, 82 };
        List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>() { DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1), DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(2), DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3) };
        string trkpt = "";

        for(int c = 0; c < heartRateList.Count; c++)
        {
            trkpt += "<trkpt>"
                + "<time>" + timeList[c].ToString("s") + "Z</time>"
                + "<extensions>"
                + "<gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>"
                + "<gpxtpx:hr>" + heartRateList[c] + "</gpxtpx:hr>"
                + "</gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>"
                + "</extensions>"
                + "</trkpt>";
        }
        
        string gpx = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
            + "<gpx xmlns=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1\" xmlns:gpxtpx=\"http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1\" xmlns:gpxx=\"http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.cluetrust.com/XML/GPXDATA/1/0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" creator=\"Zamfit\" version=\"1.3\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd\">"
            + "<metadata><time>2022-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></metadata>"
            + "<trk>"
            + "<name>Activity Name</name>"
            + "<trkseg>"
            + trkpt
            + "</trkseg>"
            + "</trk>"
            + "</gpx>";       
     
        Console.WriteLine(gpx);

    }
}
```